# how to get a function's signature that have a structre as parametter

Tags: solidity, blockchain, struct, function, abi.encodewithsignature

function createClone(
uint256 dbId,
launchpadLib.IDOInfo memory _idoInfo,
launchpadLib.IDOInfoTwo memory _IDOInfoTwo
) external{}

I have this funtion how can i make signature of this function with giving the parametters of this function?? can any one hepl???

Comment: To create a proper signature, it is important to understand the structure of the launchpadLib.IDOInfo and launchpadLib.IDOInfoTwo arguments. Knowing them will help us improve the signature creation process.